# Update field of a collection based on another collection - MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I have two collections The structure of collection A is

```
{
     id:
     product:
}
```

The structure of collection B is

```
{
     id:
     product:
     status:
}
```

I want to update collection B like if a product exists in collection A, then it will set status 1 to the corresponding document of collection B.

The SQL syntax would be like

```
UPDATE B SET B.STATUS = 1 WHERE B.PRODUCT IN (SELECT PRODUCT FROM A);
```

I just need to do the same in MongoDB. Thanks in advance.

Comment: As of v4.2, you can't access other collections in a single update query. However you can do two separate read and update queries.

Comment: I have millions of documents in those collection.. It needs to be fast. I cant read and update one by one.. Any other suggestion? @thammada.ts

Comment: OK, I take it back, from v4.2 you can use $merge as suggested by @Joe

Answer (score 2):

In MongoDB 4.2 you can do this with aggregation.

- Aggregate collection A
- [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/index.html#lookup-aggregation) from collection B with local and foreign fields both set to "product"
- [$unwind](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/index.html#unwind-aggregation) the array returned from lookup
- [$replaceRoot](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/replaceRoot/index.html#replaceroot-aggregation) to make the looked up document to root
- [$project](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/index.html#project-aggregation) `status: {$literal:1}`
- [$merge](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/merge/index.html#merge-aggregation) with collection B

Comment: I am new to MongoDB .. So can you please write down the query? @Joe